# Should a woman with many tattoos cover them whilst visiting Egypt?

Tags: safety, egypt, female-travellers

Hello Fellow Travellers!

I am a 40 year old woman from the USA. I have always wanted to travel to Egypt, but I am concerned about my tattoos. I haven't had an issue with other countries that I have visited, but they have all been in Europe and North America. But I know that Egypt is a very conservative country.

I have many of them, about 50. They cover my arms and legs (not completely, but very noticeable). I will be travelling with my husband (he's a very tall, big man).

Should I cover my tattoos at all times to avoid offending anyone or causing safety issues? Also, should I wear a head scarf throughout my trip?

Thank you kindly in advance for your advice!